# ブラウザでJavascriptによってPDFの暗号化を解除する方法

Tags: javascript, pdf

ブラウザでJavascriptによってPDFの暗号化を自動で解除する方法はあるのでしょうか．
例えば，サーバからPDFを取ってきて，特定のユーザだけパスワードを配布し，クライアント側で自動解除するようなプログラムを書きたいです．
自分の調べた範囲だとそのような方法は見つかりませんでしたのでこちらで質問させてもらいました．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

簡単に調べた範囲ですが、 Firefox で使用されている PDF.JS ではパスワードで保護されたPDFの表示もサポートされていて、デモコードも以下のページにありました。
https://usefulangle.com/post/22/pdfjs-tutorial-2-viewing-a-password-protected-pdf

但し、この方法は 暗号化済み PDF を、暗号化されていない PDF に変換するのでは無く、暗号化済み PDF を PDF.JS の PDF ビューワ で表示させるというやり方になるでしょう。